# Apache httpd custom module libpq PostgreSQL connection

Tags: c, postgresql, apache

I'm trying to create new module for apache httpd to modify request headers based on SQL query from PostgreSQL.

I have tried to use `libpq-fe.h` in order to do so. I have installed `postgresql-devel` using `yum install postgresql-devel`.

I have tried to make simple use with the libpq:

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "apr_dbd.h"
#include "mod_dbd.h"
#include "libpq-fe.h"


/* The sample content handler */
static int my_apache2_module_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    int lib_ver = PQlibVersion();
    ...
}
```

The include itself works just fine, but when I call `PQlibVersion()` function, I get `undefined symbol: PQlibVersion` error.

I have tried to copy the `libpq` libraries to `/usr/include/httpd`.

I have tried to Load the library with `LoadFile /usr/include/libpq-fe.h`, but I get `/usr/include/libpq-fe.h: invalid ELF header`

Do I need to recompile httpd, in order to use tihs library?
There is httpd library for PostgreSQL connections?

**Versions**:

PostgreSQL - 13.1

httpd - 2.4.37

libpq-devel - 12.5

## Update

Problem solved. Comipled the module and provide the linker the path to libpq libraries. Also, I have added `LoadFile /usr/lib64/libpq.so`. I have loaded the `.h` file instead of the `.so` file

Comment: How did you tell the linker to link to the library?

Comment: Thanks, I forget to add this flag. I have added the the -I flag and ran this command `apxs -i -a -c mod_my_apache2_module.c -I /usr/pgsql-10/include`, but now I get  `mod_my_apache2_module.c:5:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: OK the compilation worked, I had to change the flags order. But still get the original error  - `undefined symbol: PQlibVersion`

Comment: I have tried to add `LoadFile /usr/pgsql-10/include/libpq-fe.h` but got  `/usr/pgsql-10/include/libpq-fe.h: invalid ELF header` error

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to include the header file, you also have to link with `-l pq`.

Use `-w all` and have a look at the warnings when you compile and link.